# Get text from CComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ccombobox

I have a CDialog (`myDialogBox`) that has a `CComboBox` member (`myComboBox`). My goal is to get the user-typed text (preferably as a `CString`) from the edit portion of a dropdown style `CComboBox`. But, I cannot seem to get it to work.

I've tried using `myComboBox.GetWindowText(myString)`. But whenever I run it in debug mode, my code breaks at `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd))` within the `CWnd::GetWindowText()` function.

I've also tried `myDialogBox.GetDlgItemText(MY_COMBOBOX_ID, myString)`, which breaks down in a similar way.

Additionally, I've tried:

```
    COMBOBOXINFO info;
    memset(&info,0,sizeof(info));
    myComboBox.GetComboBoxInfo(&info);
    LPTSTR str = new TCHAR[::GetWindowTextLength(info.hwndItem)];
    ::GetWindowText(info.hwndItem,str,::GetWindowTextLength(info.hwndItem));
```

But, it doesn't seem to be populating my `info` variable correctly.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please? What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Just in case it might help understand my ultimate goal, I am trying to have a combo-box where that can help a user pic and choose from a listing of strings. Nonetheless, if he/she does not want any on the dropdown-list, he can come up with his own string. I'd like a way to receive his user-typed string.

Comment: You should have an auto-generated `DDX_Control` line in your dialog's `DoDataExchange()` method mapping `MY_COMBOBOX_ID` to `myComboBox`. Also `MY_COMBOBOX_ID` should have a unique numerical value in resource.h. Without those you'd get behaviour such as you're describing.

Comment: Refering to my second response to Mark Ransom below... I believe I have those requirements. (including the value in resource.h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `GetWindowText` before the dialog is destroyed. A good place to do that would be in the `DoDataExchange` member function of the dialog.

Edit: You can also get an error if the CComboBox object hasn't been attached to the actual window. This also typically occurs in `DoDataExchange`.

Comment: What's odd is that it's happening even when I haven't destroyed the dialog box. To check, I made a function that occurs `OnEditChangeMyComboBox`, which only does the following: `UpdatesData(TRUE)`, then it tries to get the text. It doesn't destroy the dialog or anything.

Comment: As far as `DoDataExchange`, I have `CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX); DDX_Control(pDX, MY_COMBOBOX_ID, myComboBox);`. Is that sufficient to attach it to the dialog?

Comment: @JHowzer, yes that *should* be sufficient. However the error you're getting is that there's no window attached to the object. I'm out of ideas on how that could occur.

Comment: Make sure the ID property for the control in the Dialog Editor is still in fact `MY_COMBOBOX_ID` and that it hasn't accidently been changed. If the ID is now different, then the solution will still build but the combobox won't have a valid window handle.

Comment: I realized I was missing a CString variable tied to the combo-box. This also required adding `DDX_CBString(pDX, MY_COMBO_ID, myComboString);` to `DoDataExchange`. After that, I `UpdateData(TRUE);` when selecting or editchange events occur. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @JHowzer it's good that you got it to work. I wouldn't have expected your solution to be any more successful than the others based on the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the combo box text inline with the following code:

```
CString cStr;
CWnd* Pfield = GetDlgItem(MY_COMBOBOX_ID);
Pfield->GetWindowText(cStr);
```